# Alteryx - How to Process Sharepoint input which has Drop down list values

Tags: sharepoint, alteryx

I would like to read Sharepoint data which contains attributes for a dropdown list.  I am connecting to Sharepoint using the Alteryx's Sharepoint list connector tool. Alteryx is only returning the data that is already selected from the dropdown. It is not listing the other data available to the dropdown list.

For example, below is my sample input file which has one attribute called Title1 and value is a dropdown list. (Using an Excel sample, since I cant provide the screenshot of Sharepoint since it has confidential data)

[image: Sample Input]

In the above image, under Title1, there is a dropdown list that has 6 values and data1 has been selected.

**Desired output:**

[image: Desired Output]

However, Ateryx is reading only the value that is already selected from the dropdown. 
It's showing only **data1** as an output:

**Actual output:**
[image: Alteryx Output]

Comment: Are the values for your dropdown coming from a different list or reference location?  If so, you could read from there instead.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that the Alteryx connector returns the list of files listed in the SharePoint. The actual files may be located at a different (physical) shared/network directory. You will need another permission to access the directory to read the actual files. Check with the SharePoint Admin to get the right file directory.